# no way to enter a value

Tags: c#

I just started to study C#. I copy a sample from visual basic website: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

In the example:

```
// cmdline1.cs
// arguments: A B C
    using System;

public class CommandLine
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       // The Length property is used to obtain the length of the array.
       // Notice that Length is a read-only property:
       Console.WriteLine("Number of command line parameters = {0}",
          args.Length);
       for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Arg[{0}] = [{1}]", i, args[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

I don't know how to enter a input here

When I run the code, there is no way to enter a value ,any knows why?

Comment: ...because there is no code there to ask for input. Perhaps you would be better following a tutorial rather than copying a whole snippet of code and hoping for the best.

Comment: The link you posted is from over a decade ago! Didn't you notice the date?

Comment: In addition to Simon, this sample is used to see which arguments you have passed the application if you run it like: CommandLine.exe arg1 arg2

Comment: even though I have answered, my advise to you is not to use SO for such questions.

Comment: there is no date, where did you find the date?

Comment: @Louise it is using NET 2003 ;-)

Comment: thanks Heslacher and simon W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is not for taking any inputs. It just prints the number of command line parameters, and parameters also. It is also written in the link you posted. Why do you expect it to take any input?

`Console.WriteLine()` prints the output, for taking input you should use `Console.ReadLine()`.

Here is a code that will ask what is your name and then print it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Prints a user understandable message
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your Name:");

    // takes input and store it in a string variable
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    // print output 
    Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name);
}
```

There are couple of methods for taking input and printing output:

#### For printing Output:

- Console.WriteLine()
- Console.Write()

#### For taking input:

- Console.ReadLine()
- Console.ReadKey()
- Console.Read()

What are the differences in between them? Refer to the [documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Console_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also you might wanna find a better site to start learning C#. Try this:

[Visual C# .NET Programming](http://homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html)

You can explore this for books and resources for C#:

[Stack Overflow C# Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info)

Comment: I give you a plus but I don't want to because this entire post is dumb.  I did like the link though as it reminded me of a time long ago......